# Command passed as an argument to another command is not found in PATH

Tags: bash, path

Generally when a command appears as an argument to another command e.g.

```
command1 command2
```

how is `command2`'s executable searched for?

Is it searched in `$PATH`?

Is it specific to how `command1` handles the search?

For example, I just changed `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`, and then run `source ~/.bashrc`. Then I can run `myprogram` in bash, but I have problem when running

```
$ torify myprogram
ERROR: myprogram cannot be found in PATH.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the second command is an argument to the first one (which is the actual executable being run as far as the shell is concerned), it totally depends on the first command that how it handles it's argument.

Whether the actual executable takes full path or relative path or searches through `PATH`, totally depends on it's design.

Comment: thanks. if `torify` searches `mycommand` in `$PATH`, then why "ERROR: myprogram cannot be found in PATH"?

Comment: @Tim I have not used `torify` so hard to say without checking..what happens when you use the full path? Its possible that `torify` is still using the previous `PATH` from cache..

Comment: If it uses the PATH from cache, how can I make it use the up-to-date PATH?

Comment: @Tim Check the man page..there might be some hints..its possible that you have run it beforehand and it has keet a copy of the `PATH` and reusing it..also did you `export` the `PATH`?

Comment: yes I did `export PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

`torify` uses `/bin/which` to test if `myprogram` is found in the PATH. Try using `which myprogram` yourself first. Make sure your command is executable with `chmod +x myprogram`.